# Cannot install Oracle 11g client with error OUI-10037

Tags: oracle11g

I am trying to install **Oracle 11g** client on my box that currently has **Oracle 9i** installed. I keep getting this error when I click NEXT as the wizard starts:

**OUI-10037:Unable to set up inventory. You may not have the proper  permissions**

Since I am logged in as a local **Admin**, this doesn't make much sense. The ONLY thing I've found on another forum was to **remove the file "oraInst.loc"** from my machine. But I cannot find that file anywhere on my system.

I'd really appreciate if someone can advise on a solution to this problem...

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You must run the orainstRoo.sh and then touch /oraInventory/test.txt, that works for me.
Greetings